# Display received gstreamer mjpeg on HTML page

Tags: html, video-streaming, gstreamer, mjpeg, google-coral

I am receiving with Gstreamer an mjpg stream and I have not been able to display it in a simple HTML5 page.

The send command:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw,format=YUY2,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1 ! jpegenc ! rtpjpegpay ! udpsink host=<IP> port=5600
```

The receive command:

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5600 ! application/x-rtp,encoding-name=JPEG,payload=26 ! rtpjpegdepay ! jpegdec ! autovideosink
```

The receive command works fine opening a new window that shows the stream as expected.

However, I was not able to find a way of displaying it in an HTML page.

Do you have any suggestions of what to look for since I am new in the media streaming field?

Comment: Did you go through : https://coral.withgoogle.com/docs/dev-board/camera/#run-a-demo-with-the-camera, maybe you can find something useful here.

Comment: Yes, I have read them and I was not able to find the part that the demos are displayed on a browser (maybe not included in the docs as not that important)